# Web interface blocked when javascript is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem, i'm working with websocket for update live data, the problem is when the data is updating, all web interface is blocked, i cant use the buttons scrollbars, textbox, etc. Maybe is possible work async for DOM manipulation, or another solution, i working with angularjs, jquery, and html5, please check this url [livexll.com/default.asp](http://livexll.com/default.asp).

**UPDATE:CODE**

websocket(is referential)

```
ws = new window[support]('ws://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:port/');

                    // when data is comming from the server, this method is called
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    // Here I proccess the message
    // I walk the whole message, looking at the object id
    for(.....){
       if(...){//i find the id, them i change the data
          //each materials for stundet finded
           for($x=0;$x<=evt.data[0].student[0].materials.length.....
                    $scope.data[0].Event[$idfind].BetType[$x]=evt.data[0].Event[0].BetType[$x]
          }
        }

    }
    .....
    ....
}
```

Next I show the data with angular like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="Event in data[0].Event">
   Home:{{Event.Home}}
   vs
   Home:{{Event.Away}}
   ....
   ....
   <div ng-repeat="Bet in Event .bettype">
     Away {{bet.Away}}
    home {{bet.home }}
    ...
    ....
   ....
   </div>

</div
```

It's only an example because each event(around 70) have around(20) bettype, each bettype(5-10 rows), and each message comes around (0.3 - 1.2 seconds).

Comment: I suspect you are just sending too much data and too often.  It looks to me like there is a 10-20k webSocket message being sent to the client more than once per second so your client spends all its time processing that information and updating the DOM.  One possibility is for your server to send only data that has changed and if that's still too much data, then don't send the data that often (perhaps only send updates every 10 seconds instead of every second).  Also, I didn't look into your DOM manipulation functions, but again you only want to touch the DOM if something actually changed.

Comment: the server only send the change data, and send only 1 event per message

Comment: There's too much data being sent and the client spends all its time processing this stream of data.  You will need to send less data or find a way to make the processing of the data a LOT more efficient.  I have a relatively powerful laptop and my laptop can barely keep up with the processing, but is busy most of the time.  This is just too much processing.  FYI, I think your server would likely have much higher scalability too if you weren't sending this much data this often.

Comment: the problem is that the data that update page, I do not manipulate, is a separate service, and all data is in live, if I do not hear a data, it could be harmful

Comment: I'm giving you the facts.  You're sending a lot of data to the client, more than once per second and the client is so busy processing that data that it often can't keep up and thus the UI is not responsive.  You have to send less data or make the processing of the data a LOT more efficient.  FYI, if this was viewed on a mobile device, it would drain the battery and it uses quite a bit of bandwidth (like 600-800kb per minute).  You can use Chrome's profiling to see where all the CPU time is being spent.

Comment: This article might help: https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/considering-speed-and-slowness-in-angularjs/